# expressJS/mongoDB: How to add some fixture mongoDB data on start up?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

This is how I've setup my expressjs server and my mongoDB (mongoDB native driver, not mongoose). Now I would like to check for some existing documents in the DB to add some fixture documents on start of the server.
I do not understand where to do that.

Something like:

```
const hasAdmin = db.collection('users').findOne({ username: 'admin' })
if (!hasAdmin) {
  // Add some data to collection
}
```

**app.js**

```
const app = express()
const mongoDB = mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb

// Parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// Parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))
// GraphQL
app.use('/graphql',
  bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' }),
  graphqlMiddleware,
  graphqlExpress(req => ({
    schema: schema
  }))
)

// Connect to Mongo on start
db.connect(mongodb, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to Mongo: ' + err)
    process.exit(1)
  } else {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
    })
  }
})

module.exports = app
```

Comment: For example if you are running the app for the first time, there is no data at all existing in the DB. But there should be an admin user. So the server should test, if there is an admin user in the DB. If not, it should be created...

Comment: You need to do it in a unit test that would ideally test if a connection is good to go, create the documents and test whether the document has been created and the exception test cases for al the above. 

This you would also ideally test against a mongoose schema not against the native mongo db driver because you may wish to test for additional test scenarios, in future.

Use supertst for expressjs and mocha for the unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in theory put it anywhere there is a Mongo connection open.

I would recommend to extract your database-related functionality into a separate class (and a separate file for that; [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

You could then call the functionality that fills your database initially from the constructor of that class.

Something like this (this is not working code, but should give you an idea):

**db-helper.js**

```
class DbHelper {
    constructor() {
        this.connect();
    }

    connect() {
        // establish mongo connection
        mongo.connect("...", (err, db) => {
            this.db = db;
            // then take care of initial filling
            this.ensureDatabaseIsFilled();
        });

    }

    ensureDatabaseIsFilled() {
        const hasAdmin = this.db.collection('users').findOne({ username: 'admin' })
        if (!hasAdmin) {
            // Add some data to collection
        }
    }

    /**
      * Random method that retrieves data from mongo
      */
    getRandomThing() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.find({...}, (err, result) => resolve(result));
        });
    }
}
module.exports = DbHelper;
```

**app.js**

```
const DbHelper = require('./db-helper');
const dbHelper = new DbHelper();
// ....
app.get('/example', (req, res) => {
    dbHelper.getRandomThing().then(result => res.send(result));
});
// ....
```